# Capacitor text-to-speech API not working on android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am getting this error whenever I try to execute the `TextToSpeech.speak()` function from `@capacitor-community/text-to-speech@0.2.3`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Not supported on this device.
    at n.value (29.a169ec33.chunk.js:formatted:3022)
    at n.<anonymous> (29.a169ec33.chunk.js:formatted:2842)
    at c (26.902cd79a.chunk.js:2)
    at Generator._invoke (26.902cd79a.chunk.js:2)
    at Generator.next (26.902cd79a.chunk.js:2)
    at 29.a169ec33.chunk.js:formatted:2816
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at l (29.a169ec33.chunk.js:formatted:2793)
    at n.value (29.a169ec33.chunk.js:formatted:2836)
    at 29.a169ec33.chunk.js:formatted:4997
```

Here is my code below:

```
import { TextToSpeech } from '@capacitor-community/text-to-speech';

const androidSpeak = async () => {
    await TextToSpeech.speak({
      text: 'This is a sample text.',
      locale: 'en_US',
      pitchRate: 1.0,
      speechRate: 1.0,
      volume: 1.0,
      category: 'ambient',
    });
  };
```

Whenever I trigger the function it gives me the error above. Anyone experienced it before?

Modules:
`@capacitor/android: ^2.4.2`
`@capacitor-community/text-to-speech: ^0.2.3`
https://github.com/capacitor-community/text-to-speech

Answer (score -1):

Change the language  from 'en_US' to 'en' and it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31175071)